# substitute for peripeteia

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms, greek

I was all set to release an album titled Peripeteia. I thought the word aesthetically sounded beautiful and the meaning, reversal of reality, "the moment the hero realizes all he believes is untrue" (in greek tragedy), etc. seemed very fitting to many of the songs and some of my recent personal experiences. Unfortunately, another band released an album titled Peripeteia, how random! Can't believe someone beat me to it. Does anyone know any words that have the same sort of meaning?

Comment: Quite honestly, although their pronunciations are different, to the average person, this obscure word might look too much like propecia...

Comment: @user82677: I consider myself a pretty average person, and I'd never even heard the brand name "Propecia" until now.

Comment: You seem to refer to *denouement* rather than *peripeteia*, check the respective meanings.

Comment: I was initially of the opinion that this word peripeteia was the term to describe something without an atom of substance, a term to describe a nothing.
it appears I am wrong. WB.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the definition you offer more closely matches Aristotle’s term *anagnōrisis* (ἀναγνώρισις), recognition, notably the recognition of the truth by the tragic hero: definition in Liddell-Scott-Jones lexicon [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3D%2aa%3Aentry%20group%3D128%3Aentry%3Da%29nagnw%2Frisis); usage in Aristotle’s *Poetics* 1452a [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3aabo%3atlg,0086,034:1452a:29&lang=original), where Fyfe translates *anagnōrisis* as “discovery” and *peripeteia* as “reversal.”